# Does the estimator of $P(X\leq 1)$ for Poisson distribution attain the Cramer-Rao lower bounf

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be a random sample from a Poisson distribution with mean $\mu$, $\mu>0$.

(a) Find the UMVUE of probability $P(X \leq 1)$.

(b) Does the estimator obtained in part (a) attain the Cramer-Rao lower bound? Justify your answer.

Comment: When you phrase questions in a way suitable for assigning homework, we may wonder whether there is actually some question in your mind that you're trying to communicate to us or whether you're just copying something without having made the effort to understand it first. If you have a homework assignment phrase just as above, tell us whether you understand the questions and if not, at what point you ran into difficulty, and if you did, where you ran into difficulty trying to answer them.

Comment: The indicator function $Y=\left.\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }X_1\le 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}$ is obviously an unbiased estimator of that probability.  The Lehmann–Scheffé theorem then tells us to look at the conditional expected value of that, given the value of a complete sufficient statistic.  If you know that $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is a complete sufficient statistic for this family of distributions, that gives you a place to start. ${}\qquad{}$